# How to implement idiomatic logging in a Go library?

Tags: logging, go, idioms

What is an idiomatic way to perform logging in Go?

Comment: There is bunch of 3rd party libraries which provides more feature full implementations. For example, in standard library I missed an convenient option for custom formatting and log levels (debug, info, ...) and I end up implementing my own library - [go-log](https://github.com/scale-it/go-log). Take a look at it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a file that declares a global variable **logger**. Then, use the idiomatic [*init()*](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#init) function of Go to initialize the variable on startup.

**logger.go**:

```
package xxx

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

var logger *log.Logger
func init() {
    logger = log.New(os.Stderr, "xxx: ", log.Ldate | log.Ltime | log.Lshortfile)
}
```

**example.go**:

```
func test() {
    logger.Println("Logged")
}
```

This method offers the benefit that you can use a single logger implementation that can be configured from a single file.

**EDIT:** ThomasKappler pointed out that if you are only using a single global logger, you can use the log package's inbuilt logger and configure it with SetFlags. The only difference is you must be more explicit and import the log package.

Comment: If you use only one global logger, you can skip making your own and use the log package's functions like log.Println etc. You can still configure it with log.SetFlags().

Comment: @ThomasKappler Thanks, I didn't know that. I prefer using this method because I can extend logger without breaking existing functionality (plus I don't have to import the log package everywhere)